# update application status (java cache) synchronizing with database

Tags: java, oracle, caching

I have a cache application which periodically update the internal status (hashtable) doing some select from oracle db. There is a batch which updates the cache periodically (1 min):

1. Batch reads data where `D_UPDATE > lastRunningBatch = lastUpdate` (D_UPDATE last date of row update)
2. Batch saves `lastUpdate`
3. Batch updates cache
4. After 1 minute, the batch starts again...

The issue:

1. Client updates the `row100`  with `D_UPDATE=SYSTIMESTAMP` but doesn't commit
2. Batch reads data where `D_UPDATE > lastRunningBatch`
3. Client commits
4. ...

The batch has lost the `row100`!

I cannot use Coherence, JCS, EhCache, JBOSS cache, ...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try  `ORA_ROWSCN`?

> `ORA_ROWSCN` returns the conservative upper bound system change number (SCN) of the most recent change to the row